# Как автор может отменить правку, одобренную двумя высокорейтинговыми участниками?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки, отклонённые-правки

Есть такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248744/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5-unity-3d).
Если зайти в его историю правок, то можно увидеть, что в первой его версии было большое количество ненужных слов, затрудняющих понимание: `собственно`, `сорян`, `только начал кодить`, `собственно к проблеме`, `Не судите строго`.

Я внес правку, удалив все эти фразы и по мелочи подправив опечатку в слове `управления`. В описании правки я так и написал: сократил ненужное.

Мое правка была одобрена двумя довольно высокорейтинговыми участниками:

- [S. Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217323/s-nick) (рейтинг на данный момент 33895)
- [aleksandr barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178576/aleksandr-barakin) (рейтинг на данный момент (63794)

Ввиду этого, правка была принята. Сегодня я неожиданно для себя обнаруживаю, что моя последняя правка была отменена. Захожу на этот вопрос и вижу такое - странное на мой взгляд - сообщение:

```
Принятая правка отменена автором сообщения или модератором.
```

Причем, рядом указано имя автора вопроса [HEEELP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/431617/heeelp) (Новый участник сообщества).

Меня интересует два вопроса:

- Как вообще может быть такое, что новый еще не оперившийся участник сообщества может отменять правку, одобренную 30 и 60 "тысячниками", пусть даже и на своем вопросе.
- Действительно ли `собственно`, `сорян`, `Не судите строго` являются "способом самовыражения автора" и мне не следует их удалять? (Я уверен, ответ на этот вопрос: нет, не являются; но как тогда получилось, что правка была отменена?)

Может я неправильно понимаю сообщение от сайта и правка была отменена вовсе не ТС?
Действительно ли корректным является факт возможности отмены уже принятой правки низкорейтинговым автором вопроса, если не задета суть вопроса?

Comment: ни раз видела, что участник с меньшей репутацией, чем у меня принимает/проверяет мои правки. [вот пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxpGY.png) [такой правки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCMsd.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Это нормальная ситуация. Автор сообщения имеет эксклюзивное право отклонять принятые правки.

Более того, любой участник с 2К+ репутации может вносить правки в сообщения самостоятельно или производить откат к определённой версии (что в данном случае было сделано автором).

Репутация ревьюверов вообще не имеет никакого значения в данном случае, главное, что они уже являются ревьюверами (получена соответствующая привилегия по достижении 2k репутации).

Comment: Разве это правильно, что участник, который, очевидно, пока не понимает, зачем вообще нужны правки, может отменять полезную правку. Понятно, что он, скорее всего, действует по методу "не трогайте мой вопрос. Он хорош таким, каким Я его написал", но?

Comment: @МаксимФисман ревизию уже откатили, так что не расстраивайтесь. Скоро у вас тоже будет 2К репы и сможете править самостоятельно.

Comment: Что такое править самостоятельно? То есть без проверки других участников?

Comment: @МаксимФисман да, возможность редактировать любое сообщение. Кроме заблокированных.

Comment: `Не расстраивайтесь` - да мне вообще плев... все равно. Меня смущает сама суть и возможность 

Comment: @МаксимФисман было бы плевать, наверное, не задавали бы об этом вопросы. Но это даже хорошо, что не плевать.

Comment: Ну да, верно....

Comment: @МаксимФисман,  `Разве это правильно, что участник, который, очевидно, пока не понимает, зачем вообще нужны правки, может отменять полезную правку` Хех, вы посмотрите [вот эту историю правок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1194531/revisions)

Comment: @wololo  Все, теперь мне понятна глубина ситуации. Интересно, а тот, кто боролся с автором реально каждый раз получал по +2 балла репутации за каждую правку? 

Comment: @МаксимФисман при самостоятельных правках репутация не даётся

Answer (score 6):

Правки существуют для того, чтобы *помочь* автору вопроса правильнее сформулировать свой вопрос. Именно поэтому правки, изменяющие смысл вопроса, не одобряются.*

Поскольку, очевидно, автор вопроса лучше знает, что именно он хотел сказать своим вопросом, то именно у автора вопроса должно быть последнее слово. Он может принять или отвергнуть помощь, если изменения (по его мнению) вовсе не улучшают вопрос.

Если вопрос плох, поставьте минус. Нет смысла спорить с автором о том, что именно он хотел спросить; если вы хотите спросить нечто существенно другое, спросите это самостоятельно отдельным вопросом.

---

*За несколькими исключениями, наподобие грубого нарушения законов. Эти исключения, кажется, обсуждались здесь, на Мете.

Comment: О, VladD вернулс... Кхм-кхм... Спасибо, наверное, действительно, такие вопросы лучше минусовать, оставляя комментарий, чтобы отобразить отношение сообщества и дать автору вопроса осознать ошибку.

Comment: @МаксимФисман: Ну, я ненадолго. Если автор отвергает помощь по улучшению вопроса, и вопрос плохой, то конечно стоит минусовать. Мы можем лишь предложить помощь, но не спорить с активно протестующим автором.

Comment: `Ну, я ненадолго` А чего так? Вроде бы годные ответы пишите...

Comment: @wololo: Ну, пару лет назад был конфликт с администрацией, из-за которого многие активные участники ушли. Поскольку с тех пор ничего не изменилось, то и возвращаться нет особых причин.